# Using sizeof with struct with fixed length array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, sizeof

Is it good coding practice, to use sizeof(struct) when the struct has a fixed length array?

```
#define NUM_TRACKS 10
#define NUM_SAMPLES 250
typedef struct _DATA_PROC
{
    uint16_t count[NUM_TRACKS] ;
    int16_t data[NUM_TRACKS][NUM_SAMPLES];
} tDataProcessing ;



tDataProcessing* tDp = malloc(sizeof(tDataProcessing)) ;
```

Comment: Some relavant issues for others reading this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662381/using-sizeof-with-struct-with-fixed-length-array

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: i want to make sure that some compilers do not interpret it as:
typedef struct _DATA_PROC
{
    uint16_t* count ;
    int16_t** data ;
} tDataProcessing ;

Comment: Please put code in the question, it's not readable in a comment. And no, it won't do that. `sizeof` will give you the size you need to store the object. The arrays are within the object itself, not pointed to by it.

Comment: No compiler is allowed to misinterpret the struct in the question as `typedef struct _DATA_PROC { uint16_t* count; int16_t** data; } tDataProcessing;` — at least, it can't claim to be a standard-conforming C compiler if it does.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to use the pointer variable itself rather than the type:

```
tDataProcessing *tDp = malloc(sizeof *tDp);
```

This is sometimes clearer in cases with pointers buried in types and such.

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually safe since you dereference the uninitialized `tDp`, even though you don't do anything with it. I believe the argument to `sizeof` can still have side-effects occur.

Comment: @ThomasJager: It's fine — `sizeof` doesn't dereference the pointer.  I'm not sure this is an answer to the question, but what it suggests is kosher.

Comment: Yes, sizeof does not evaluate its expression.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, ok, I confused it being able to have side-effects with it always having side-effects.

Comment: This is safer in case the type of `tDp` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

For starters in expressions, with rare exceptions including the `sizeof` operator, arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their element types.

So for example the array

```
int16_t data[NUM_TRACKS][NUM_SAMPLES];
```

is converted in expressions like

```
int16_t ( *data )[NUM_SAMPLES];
```

not as you wrote in a comment like

```
int16_t** data
```

However a declaration is not an expression. So the `sizeof` operator returns the number of bytes to accommodate all data members of the structure without any implicit conversion.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
>   the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N];

    printf( "sizeof( a ) = %zu\n", sizeof( a ) );

    struct A
    {
        int a[N];
    };

    printf( "sizeof( struct A ) = %zu\n", sizeof( struct A ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( a ) = 40
sizeof( struct A ) = 40
```